# ng-repeat item limitTo and custom ng-repeat filter item limitTo

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Example code

There are three ***type***   web, tab and mobile in this json

**Target** :

1) ng-repeat limitTo:6

2) Type **mobile** limitTo: 2

```
 {
     type: 'web',
     data:  'lipsum....'
    },
    {
     type: 'mobile',
     data:  'lipsum....'
    },
    {
     type: 'tab',
     data:  'lipsum....'
    },
    {
     type: 'web',
     data:  'lipsum....'
    },
    {
     type: 'mobile',
     data:  'lipsum....'
    },
    {
     type: 'tab',
     data:  'lipsum....'
    }
```

**Target** :

1) ng-repeat limitTo:6

2) Type **mobile** limitTo: 2

```
<div ng-repeat="work in works.work | limitTo:6 | filter: ">
```

Comment: do you want to show only mobile type with limit 2?

Comment: yes , Dont show more than two mobile items

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, this is what you required,

```
<div ng-repeat="res in data|filter:{type:'mobile'} | limitTo:2 ">
        {{res.data}}
 </div>
```

Working [`App`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/2j3p8f2h/)